# Prison(?) satellite orbiting earth

Tags: story-identification, movie, space

I've been trying for years to track down a sci-fi film I saw probably back in the 80/90's. I only ever saw the last few minutes of it and it seemed to show someone running along corridors (presumably from his pursuers) in attempt to escape. He then comes up to a large window, and looking out he sees the Earth below, and the final shot if I recall correctly is the look of realisation on his face at the futility of his situation.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Can you describe the appearance of the man and/or the vessel? Also, are you certain this is a film, rather than an episode of a series?

Comment: I wondered if it might be Escape from DS-3, but that ends with the prisoners leaving on a freighter.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the greeting. As I say, I only saw the last few minutes and all of the action was within the spaceship/satellite. I cannot describe the man, this was after all probably 30+ years ago. I might be mis-remembering but I think the final shot was looking back at the man from space and drawing back just enough to establish that this was a space vessel.

Comment: View of a prisoner in space might also fit [*Fortress 2*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0179183/), though again, that's not how it ends.  (It's also probably too late for your time period, since it was released in 2000.)  My first thought was also [*Escape from DS-3*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0123825/).

Comment: Video link: [Escape from DS-3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SSp6tIiRWMQ)

Comment: So was he unaware that he was in space before?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not Escape from DS-3; the point is that he doesn't escape.